# Nodejs and Angular5 authoritzation

Tags: node.js, angular, authorization

I want to build a web application using angular5 and nodejs. As both front-end and back-end are going to be hosted on same server. I don't want to use any REST API. I have already managed to communicate the front and the back but now I'm wondering what is the best approach to make the authorization and authentication.

I found that most people recommend jwt, but I think that this approach is only for the REST API's.

Comment: I don't think JWTs are not only for REST apis.

Comment: David is correct .Actually you can use jwt as you like they are not only for REST API's